# Nuxt 3 with client-side only rendering doesn't load

Tags: single-page-application, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I want to build a client-side only application via Nuxt 3, and just as the docs describe [here](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/deploy/static-hosting#client-side-only-rendering) I've added `ssr: false` to my nuxt config.

I then used the `nuxi build` command to build the application, but it still says it needs to be run using node.[image: Output from nuxi build]

I proceed to run `nuxi generate` as I would normally do for static hosting.
[image: Output from nuxi generate]

According to the output from the generate command, I should be able to just deploy the public folder to any static web hosting. However, when I do this, I just get a completely white page.

I have tried running the same commands without `ssr: false`, and that does render a page, but that causes none of my javascript to work.

### Edit: minimal reproducible example

So I've just follewd [these steps](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/quick-start/#new-project) from the nuxt docs.

Without making any code changes, except for editing my nuxt config, I've run `generate`.

This is what my nuxt config looks like right now;

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: false,
})
```

I then ran `npx serve .output/public` as suggested in the comments, and that seemed to work just fine locally.

I then copied the public folder to my web server, but the same issue persists, just a white screen is visible.

Maybe I should clarify my question a little more: is it still possible to host a nuxt SPA, without running a node process on the server, just as it was before in nuxt 2?

Right now I just switched to a server rendered application, as I don't see another solution.

Comment: If you want to run an SPA, `generate` is enough. Then, you could try to run it locally with something like `npx serve .output/public`. If it works locally, then deploy it to Netlify. Otherwise, if it's not working that means that this is not a build issue but a code issue. Hence, some relevant snippets will be needed then (or even a [repro]).

Comment: Hi @kissu thanks for the quick reply! I've just created a new nuxt 3 project from scratch and ran `npx serve .output/public` locally. That does in fact work just fine, however, when I then copy the `.output/public` folder to my web server, I just see a white screen as before. Right now I've switched to a server rendered application, which does work as expected, but I wonder if it's still possible to deploy an SPA without running a node process on the web server?

Comment: You don't need to have a Node.js instance for an SPA only setup. Meanwhile, you still need to use a lightweight server for that (to handle security, protocols, HTTP calls etc...), you can't only open that in your browser with a `file://` protocol. Good news, most of the places do that for you for free. Try to drop your folder here https://app.netlify.com/drop

Comment: What hosting are you using, maybe a nginx container?

Comment: @Dav3rs I'm using nginx. But I switched to Server Side Rendering and created a reverse proxy using nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Using NGINX to serve a static generated build will fail currently, because nginx do not support the MIME type for mjs files (sended as octet-stream).

To fix it just add "application/javascript" as mimetype for mjs files in the nginx configuration.

Example to adapt to your needs:

1- Create in your project root folder a file named "nginx.conf" with:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    types 
    {
        application/javascript mjs;
    }
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

With "include /etc/nginx/mime.types;" we are loading the default nginx mime types, and after that extending that list with "application/javascript mjs;".

2 - Then you could use that file in your image build step as follow (check the line 2):

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY .output/public /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now you can deploy the image. Enable the gzip line if you are not using compresion already.